# Angular 2 Routing with params along with other string

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I want to have following pattern in the route. 
Pattern:

```
"abc/test-:foo"
```

In Angular 2 I am getting

```
URL Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'abc/test-boo'
```

I have tried the same in AngularJs(1) it works fine, I am able to extract **foo** from stateParams.

Answer (score 1):

`:foo` can't be a substring of a segment, a parameter needs to take the whole part like

```
abc/test-/:foo
```

You can implement a custom https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/UrlSerializer-class.html to achieve that though.

Answer (score 0):

We solved it thanks gunter for pointing me to right class. 
Here is the code snippet

Define the pattern as

```
abc/test-/:foo
```

Then in the code

```
import {UrlSerializer, UrlTree, DefaultUrlSerializer} from "@angular/router";
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
@Injectable()
export class MySerializer implements UrlSerializer {
  defaultUrlSerializer: DefaultUrlSerializer;

  constructor() {
    this.defaultUrlSerializer = new DefaultUrlSerializer();
  }

  parse(url: string): UrlTree {
    url = url.replace("test-", "test-/");
    return this.defaultUrlSerializer.parse(url);

  }

  serialize(tree: UrlTree): string {
    return this.defaultUrlSerializer.serialize(tree).replace("test-/", "test-");
  }
}
```

Also make sure you have included this in the provider list

```
 providers: [{
      provide: UrlSerializer, useClass: MySerializer
    }
 ]
```